# Objective-C. Coredata managed context for keep Predicate in NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

1) I have `NSFetchedResultsController` with some Collection Views and I use **defaultManagedObjectContext** to keep context for it, which one is `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` and it set, as a child for `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`.

2) I have `NSArray` of `NSStrings` taken from CoreData in same **defaultManagedObjectContext**. This string I use like `predicate`, like filters option in window below. Filter works as it should.

3) And I have method to change Collection View element (for example, set LIKE) in another **backgroundManagedObjectContext** (`NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`), it set as child for **defaultManagedObjectContext**. Likes button works as it should.

But when I trying to use together (Predicate and Set like method), CoreData down with error:

> The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an
>   NSArray or an NSSet.

Should I use another context to keep predicate?

As child for **defaultManagedObjectContext**?

**Predicate like this:**

```
[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"NMObject"
            inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
self.selectedTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"музей", nil];
_predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY types.typeObjValue IN %@", self.selectedTypes];
```

So, `NMObject` has relationship with `NMTypeObj` as `NMObject types <<-----> NMTypeObj objects`

Comment: This looks more like one of your predicate formats are wrong. Search for those using "ALL" or "ANY" and see which of them does not point to array. It might be some relation which you forgot to set to "many" in your database model.

Comment: @MaticOblak I think there is no problem with format of predicate. Because it work as  it should. But not set Like, but if I comment this line: `[fetchRequest setPredicate:_predicate];` which set some Filter predicate for `NSFetchedResultsController`, button set LIke works fine.

Comment: I agree with Matic Oblak, show your predicate declaration please

Comment: @RomanSimenok updated post and add some snippet

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody!

The problem was with predicate format. if relationship is `NMObject types <<--Many to One--> NMTypeObj objects` is possibly to use ANY. Correct relationship for ANY is, for example, `NMObject types <--One to Many-->> NMTypeObj objects`

So, in my case, I change predicate to:

```
_predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"types.typeObjValue IN %@", self.selectedTypes];
```

Comment: I would prefer at least in answer that you explain what and why the issue was. Then what the solution is. From the current situation it is hard to tell what is what.